# How to reliably clear cache in Safari 12.0 while web development

Tags: caching, safari, browser-cache

I am trying to figure out how one can reliably prevent Safari 12.0 from caching files (specifically .js files in my scenario).

I need to optimise page for both iOS and macOS users and during development I've came across a weird behaviour when Safari sticks with old version of files instead of getting a newest from the server.

It got to the point when I removed file from the server and yet somehow Safari is still 'able' to display it. Of course displaying old version of the file. The rest of the browsers (Chrome, Opera, Firefox) correctly yields 404 error.

I've tried

- deleting cache with 'Empty caches' from 'Develop' menu,
- refreshing page with command+option+R,
- clearing cache through inspect mode,
- clicking refresh while holding shift,
- using incognito mode,
- deleting all website data in Privacy settings,
- quit and reopen Safari,
- combinations of all former.

And no success so far.. Safari pretends to be everything fine - continuing working with old version of file.

Does anybody else encounter such issues with caching?

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: A solution may be available here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/311113/62697. 1. You open Web Inspector on the "Elements" tab (`option⌥` + `command⌘` + `I`). 2. You refresh (`command⌘` + `R`)